# how to use one string to match many rules？

Tags: java, regex

**Conditions:**

1. there are many rules ,maybe hundreds, which are like :
   `{aab*, aabc*,
   aabcdd*, dtctddds*,
   *ddt*,
   *cddt*,
   *bcddt*,
   *t,
   *ttt,
   *ccddttt}`
2. each time I will get one string, then I should find the longest matched rule.

**Examples:**

example 1.string is `aabcddttt` the matched rule should be: `aabcdd*`

example 2. string is `accddttt` the matched rule should be `*ccddttt`

**Question:**
I don't want to use the rules in a long array to match the string one by one,that is inefficient method.maybe I should use the string as a  regex to match the hundred rules.But yet I can't find a elegant way to solve this problem.

1. Can I use some regexes to get the result?
2. Which is the best/fastest way to match?

Java, plain C or shell are preferred,please don't use C++ STL

Comment: Is this an assignment? What have you tried?

Comment: no,it's not an assignment.It's a small task in my colleague's work.I have tried some methods like the first answer below,but i think it's not the best way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try matching them all at once with a brackets around each sub-rule.  You could use the group to determine which matched.

```
public static void main(String... ignored) {
    for (String test : "aabaa,wwwaabcdddd,abcddtxyz".split(",")) {
        System.out.println(test + " matches " + longestMatch(test, "aab*", "aabc*", "aabcdd*", "dtctddds*", "ddt"));
    }
}

public static String longestMatch(String text, String... regex) {
    String[] sortedRegex = regex.clone();
    Arrays.sort(sortedRegex, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return o2.length() - o1.length();
        }
    });
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String sep = "(";
    for (String s : sortedRegex) {
        sb.append(sep).append('(').append(s).append(')');
        sep = "|";
    }
    sb.append(")");
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(sb.toString()).matcher(text);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        for (int i = 2; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
            String group = matcher.group(i);
            if (group != null)
                return sortedRegex[i - 2];
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

prints

```
aabaa matches aabc*
wwwaabcdddd matches aabcdd*
abcddtxyz matches ddt
```

Comment: Is it better than using one by one matching?

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov It depends on how smart the `compile()` is.  It may be able to simplify the duplication of searches, or performance wise it might be worse.  You would have to test it to see.  If the query can be pre-built as one, it might be better.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: The OP's "rules" look like globs to me.  You need to translate them to regex by replacing `*` with `.*` and adding anchors.  Or use the `matches()` method instead of `find()`, and never mind the anchors.

Comment: @AlanMoore I agree that the OP is likely to need to change the code to suit his/her actual requirements.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I just change the * to .* and add the ^,$ to the begin and end postion of patterns, and it works! I think the long grouped pattern string idea maybe better than the use iteration to match the string each time.

Answer (score 1):

[Longest common substring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem)

Perhaps this algorithm is what you are looking for =).

---

Why not do it simply?

```
String[] rules = {"^aab", "bcd", "aabcdd$", "dtctddds$", "^ddt$", "^cddt$", "^bcddt$", "^t", "^ttt", "^ccddttt"};
        String testCase = "aabcddttt";

        for (int i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(rules[i]);
            Matcher m = p.matcher(testCase);
            if (m.find()) {
                System.out.println("String: " + testCase + " has matched the pattern " + rules[i]);
            }
        }
```

So basically in this case, rules[0], which is ^aab found because carrot (^) means string must begin with ^aab. On the other hand, bba$ means string must end with bba. And rules[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem) is found because it means the rule can appear anywhere from the testCase (e.g. bcd).